# Should we use packages like Java style on Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm developing a new project using Scala and i was wondering if we should use packages like Java style or just create a folder like "controllers" under app folder.

What is best practice when we are developing on Scala? Create a simple folder like "models" or something like "com.mycompany.myproject.models"?

Thank in advance.

Comment: The Scala style guide recommends using java package naming conventions:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#packages

Answer (score 1):

I would use packages. this helps, when deploying stuff and raises the interoperability with Java libraries.